# Actionfunction doesn't work

Tags: actionfunction, parameters

I cannot find the reason of this situation.
Please help experts.

I have several actionfunction and all of them are using for saving value to Controller variables.

I this situation, one of them doesn't work even if I tried so many modification..

Code is here

```
<apex:form>
            <apex:commandLink action="{!passParam2}" value="Submit" 
                target="_blank" 
                styleClass="btn btn-primary" 
                style="padding: 4px; text-decoration: none;" 
                reRender="resultPanel" 
                status="myStatus">
                <apex:param name="firstparam" assignTo="{!bookingid}" value="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.bookingid}"/>

            </apex:commandLink>
        </apex:form>
```

Controller code

```
public PageReference passParam2(){
    bookingid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('bookingid');
    PageReference pg = Page.page1;
    pg.setRedirect(true);
    return pg;
}
```

Edited 1 time!

If you have any clue for resolving the issue, please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not surprised it doesn't work... but what are you actually attempting to do?

Comment: just want to save value from parameter to controller variable. Is there any way to do it easily?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a efficient approach with the use of `apex:commandLink`. No need to use `actionFunction`

As per your code, you want to display a `Submit` button and onclicking you will assign value to `bookingid`, as well as calling controller method `passParam` and navigate to visualforce page.

- button class with help you to display as `button`.
- `apex:param` will pass value to controller
- `action` will call controller method.

Visualforce

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!passParam}" 
    value="Submit" 
    target="_blank" 
    styleClass="btn" 
    style="padding: 4px; text-decoration: none;" 
    reRender="resultPanel" 
    status="myStatus">
        <apex:param name="firstparam" 
           assignTo="{!bookingid}" value="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.bookingid}"/>
</apex:commandLink>
```

Controller

```
public String bookingid {get; set;}

public PageReference passParam(){

    //navigate to visualforce page. 
    PageReference pg = Page.page1;
    pg.setRedirect(true);
    return pg;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Santanu.
In your code, I cannot find assigning part {!$CurrentPage.parameters.bookingid}.

How can I set {!$CurrentPage.parameters.bookingid} as the source for your code?

Comment: you can get that parameter in controller itself. using `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('bookingid');`

Comment: Thank you for help but....

I adjusted what you guide me. and still value show me 'NaN' when I pop it with alert..

Comment: Can you pass `value` as my updated code

Comment: Doesn't work.. sorry. It's really wired. I cannot understand T_T

Comment: I edited my questiona as current code